# What is the equivalent resistance of the circuit below?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, resistance

I want to use a method to simplify this circuit to reach it's equivalent resistance.Do you have any idea?I don't want to use directly mesh and node method.
[image]

Comment: If you do not want to use Mesh or Nodal analysis there is not much you can do aside from simulating it. . . Just from how the circuit is drawn, it looks scarier than it actually is.

Comment: Redraw the circuit, do a star-delta conversion, simplify all, repeat, ???, profit.

Comment: Isn't it just 1ohms, or am I missing something (I'm probably missing something, its one of those days)?

Comment: Yes, I'm more sure its 1ohm, its 2 dividers with 2 * 1ohm in series. Each limb is 2 ohms, so in parallel its 1 ohm. The 6 resistors on the left don't do anything, they are across the mid points of the dividers.

Comment: @user1582568 Yes,that's right.thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJE3gR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Redrawn like this you can see the answer is (1ohm + 1ohm) parallel with (1ohm + 1ohm) = 1ohm!

Comment: The original has a resistor going from A to 1 ohm off B.  I don't see that in yours.  Can you show us how you got to your diagram, because it looks incorrect to me.

Comment: @ScottSeidman R3

Comment: @Chu - The other resistors don't matter. The 4 1-ohm resistors connected to A and B do form a balanced bridge, with 0 volts between the junctions. With 0 volts across all the other resistors, no current is drawn, and the value of the other resistors is irrelevant. No matter what their values, no current is drawn.

Comment: @Chu 1 + 1 and 1 + 1 all equal and balanced bridge.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, my mistake.

Comment: I stand corrected!

Answer (score 0):

Redraw the circuit
[image]
And find equivalent resistance.